# Storing text message in a temp space

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to design a discussion forum where i want to archive the text messages and store it in a folder(or any place using path). Whenever the user again logs in and want to continue i want to extract it and display the previous chat. So  question is am i doing correct design in archiving text and retrieving it again ? If yes what is the best format to archive the text (.pdf or .csv or .txt) and store it in a place suggested by path (path info is stored in mysql) or in a folder and folder path in mysql. 
The discussion forum looks like twitter. Please throw some light on the design part. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you store your messages in the DB as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't be better to work directly in the database?
That way you can store all information in a organized and indexed way.

All you need is create your tables and columns attempting to the data size. Like VARCHAR(NUM OF BYTES) or TEXT() for a long text.

For any additional content, like attachment or answers, you can use other tables referencing the original table throught Primary Key column.

Comment: I can store in database, but right now i want to store in a place (a folder kind of thing in cloud space). I am selling the space to customers so i would like to know how much space they have used for discussion. More over whenever user logs in he can able to see the messages (unzipping from the space and dispalying using java)

Comment: Any one can help me in resolving this.

Comment: I still recommend using DB. You can calculate the used space by many forms, one of them is counting the number of letters (text only) + the attachment sizes...

Comment: Thanks Marcos, i accept your answer to store in database, thats more precise way.